# Why the service doesn't start

Tags: android, service

I'm starting to develop for android, and I'm having an issue about services. I did a lot of research about this, but couldn't find a solution.

I'm doing an app that collects RFID tags information. For that, I'm using a third-party middleware that handles the bluetooth connection to the RFID reader and other events (like connecting, reading, errors etc). So, my app creates a broadcast receiver that handles all the message and data intents sent by the middleware. For this part, everything's fine.

The problem is that I'm trying to start middleware service using the code below (provided by the middleware documentation), but it doesn't work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.supplier.middleware.runner");
intent.setPackage("com.supplier.middleware");
startService(intent);
```

I'm currently using an Asus Zenfone MAX M1 (ASUS_X00HD) with Android 8.1.0. The documentation also describes a way to stop the service (which I must use when I close the app), and the stop service intent works. So, if I start the middleware manually and try to close programatically, it works fine.

After some days trying - unsuccessfully - to solve this, I tested my app with a Motorola Moto Maxx (which is Android 6, I think) and with a Samsung J1 (which is Android 5.1.1) and both smartphones **worked fine**: when I call the startService, a notification item appears; when I call stopService, the notification item goes away.

I also tried to use "startForegroundService" because of the Android 8, but no success either.

Is there a way to "monitor" the startService calls, so maybe I could track any error? Am I doing something wrong - or rather, am I not doing something that is important?

Comment: What is in the logs?

Comment: Marcin, sorry but I don't haver any log about this. I actually tried to track some kind of log, but it seems that "startservice" in the way I'm using doesn't produce any log.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 8.0 background service limitation.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html
You can use  **JobIntentService** instead of intent service. It can work.